# Restful way to design entites type.

Tags: rest

We have scheme like:

```
class Entity: 
    pass

class BigEntity(Entity):
    pass

class RedEntity(Entity):
    pass
```

Which way to represent them in REST is better:

1. Create endpoint like `/entities/` and put entity type in request?
2. Create endpoints like `/entities/red/`, `/entities/big/`? How to deal with list of all entities in this case?

Comment: What's the difference between the three of them ? I'do go with `/entities` and `/entities?type=red`

Comment: @SimonDepelchin, there are more than 3 of them. They have different sets of fields, but have common fields also.

Comment: You can append multiple fields together. `/entities?type=red,big&commonField=xyz`

Comment: Solution with `?type=red` implemented, but looks inflexible. That's why I'm trying to understand, will expanding of entities to urls lead to improve of flexibility or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose a solution that makes it feel clean for you. There is no magic solution.

I wouldn't recommend using `/entities/red/` and `/entities/big/` because as a developer you expect `/entities/{id}` and not `/entities/{type}`.

You could use query parameters like `/entities?type=red`. It's clean too but maybe will be harder to maintain in your controllers.

Another solution might be `/red-entities/`, `/big-entities/`, `/entities`. It's clean, understandable and maintainable. It's the solution I prefer.

At the end of the day it really depends what feels cleaner and best understandable to you.

Comment: Looks like different entity type is different resource. API became clear after switching to `/entity/{type}/{id}`, and best improvement we've got on POST / PUT requests.

Answer (score 1):

REST design is mostly about depicting your resources in a structure like format. Both the options provided by you are fine depending on the requirements of your API.

If you have a lot of different types of entities (red, big, etc.) I would prefer `/entities?type=red`. For this your structure would be something like `/entities/entity-id`

If you don't have a lot of types to deal with (red, big, etc.) and you don't plan on introducing a lot more then it might be better to go with `/entities/red`. For this structure your entities as `/entities/red/entity-red-id`